# JSON.parse fails to parse with Unable to Process items SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 2

Tags: javascript, php

I have this JavaScript code and while trying to collect details value
all other values from JSON are correctly passed to respective fields but the details field fails with below error. I have tried all sorts of array and different combination for details object

`Unable to Process items SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 2`

Here is my PHP and JavaScript code,
it fails at this line.

```php
let items = JSON.parse(data.details);
```

However  `console.log(data.details)` prints details field value correctly.

JavaScript

```js
function processOrderItems(data) {
    try {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.details);

        if (data && data.details) {
            let orderItems = "";
            console.log('oujyiu');

            let items = JSON.parse(data.details);
            console.log(items);
            console.log('345353');

            items.forEach((item) => {
                orderItems = orderItems + `${item.c} X ${item.p}` + "\n";
            });
            data.orderItems = orderItems;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Unable to Process items", err);
    }
}
```

console.log(data)  **output**

```json
{
    "tagId": "Ask_for_payment",
    "tags": "Shipping_Pending",
    "phone": "917980730935",
    "encoded-payload": "eyJ0YWdJZCI",
    "name": "#",
    "customerName": "Ravi",
    "status": "confirmed",
    "fulfillmentStatus": "unfulfilled",
    "paymentStatus": "Paid",
    "id": "9024033",
    "ids": "9024033true",
    "createdOn": "July 25, 2022",
    "trackingNumber": "-NA-",
    "address": "Not avialable",
    "pd-clickable": "pd-clickable-order-div",
    "lineItems": "",
    "details": "65ttgtest prodct",
    "hide-line-items-div": "pd-hidden",
    "hiddenLineItems": "",
    "currency": "₹",
    "total": "1310.98",
    "collapse-icon": "true",
    "is_hide": "",
    "expand-icon": "true",
    "readableAddress": "Not avialable",
    "hide-div": "pd-hidden",
    "card-index": 30,
    "can-hide": ""
}
```

PHP

```php
$finaldataa .= '{"tagId":"'.$fertrr.'","tags":"'.$djjrjr.'","phone":"'.$phone_noyyy.'","encoded-payload":"kkjhjjhhh","name":"#'.$order_number.'","customerName":"'.$customer_name.'","status":"Confirmed","fulfillmentStatus":"'.$kkekffddf.'","paymentStatus":"Paid","id":"'.$idggg.'","ids":"'.$idggg.'","createdOn":"'.$time_created.'","trackingNumber":"'.$tracking_no.'","address":"Not avialable","pd-clickable":"true","lineItems":"65ttg'.$prod_title.'","details":"65ttg'.$prod_title.'","hide-line-items-div":"false","hiddenLineItems":"false","currency":"'.$s_currency.'","total":"'.$amount.'","collapse-icon":"true","is_hide":"true","expand-icon":"true"},';
```

Comment: `data.details` is `"65ttgtest prodct"` which is not a valid JSON string. Therefore `let items = JSON.parse(data.details);` will throw an error

Comment: @ruleboy21 can u plz guide what should i send there ?? for details field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you generate wrong JSON because you're doing it manually.
PHP has a built-in function to generate JSON - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
So, use built-in `json_encode` function instead of string concatenation.

Here is an example:

```php
$items = [
    ['tagId' => 'Ask_for_payment 1', /* your other props */],
    ['tagId' => 'Ask_for_payment 2', /* your other props */],
];

$json = json_encode($items, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json; // Will print: [{"tagId":"Ask_for_payment 1"},{"tagId":"Ask_for_payment 2"}]
```

Comment: still sends same error. seems, i am doing some mistake for details field

Comment: @sujtafy pls share what exactly console.log(data); prints

Comment: @sujtafy in your question the "details" field is a string, not JSON string. "65ttgtest prodct", you should not call JSON.parse on not JSON string.

Comment: what should i pass in details field so that it is parsed as json ??

Comment: @sujtafy I guess you should not touch the "details" fields, instead add new field named "items" and then iterate over data.items field. And also as I see you have already JSON parsed object on your JS side, so JSON.Parse(data.items) is not needed

Comment: thx. we will update once we fix. thx for guiding

Comment: you were right, i was sending wrong data